# ¿Cómo usar append en Python con variables dinámicas creadas con exec()?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Muy bien, el propósito de este programa es bien específico, en una lista quiero guardar una serie de cartas, telegramas o bultos que van llegando a una oficina de correo, entonces quiero guardar cada uno (diferente) en una lista llamada CARTA, para el caso de las cartas, el problema me da cuando utilizo append() ya que cuando muestro las cartas en este caso que se ha guardado en la lista CARTA, muestra todas las cartas que en teoría he introducido, EL PROBLEMA es que todas tienen la misma información!! como si append introdujera la misma carta siempre, y no sé que pasa. Ayuda!

```
 
CARTA = []
TELEGRAMA = []
BULTO = []
agg = "s"
x = 0
```

carta = [[None] * 2 for i in range(5)]
carta[0][0] = "Nombre del destinatario: "
carta[1][0] = "Direccion del destinatario: "
carta[2][0] = "Nombre del remitente: "
carta[3][0] = "Fecha de envio: "
carta[4][0] = "Nacionalidad: "

telegrama = [[None] * 2 for i in range(5)]
telegrama[0][0] = "Nombre del destinatario: "
telegrama[1][0] = "Direccion del destinatario: "
telegrama[2][0] = "Nombre del remitente: "
telegrama[3][0] = "Cantidad de palabras: "
telegrama[4][0] = "Impuesto aplicado: "

bulto = [[None] * 2 for i in range(5)]
bulto[0][0] = "Nombre del destinatario: "
bulto[1][0] = "Direccion del destinatario: "
bulto[2][0] = "Nombre del remitente: "
bulto[3][0] = "Peso: "
bulto[4][0] = "Urgencia de entrega: "

accion = int(raw_input ("""Buenas noches, oficina de correos. ¿Que accion desea realizar?

1- Recibir correspondencia
2- Despachar correspondencia
3- Entregar correspondencia personalmente\n\n>"""))

if accion == 1:
    tcorreo = int(raw_input("""Que tipo de correspondencia es la que trae?

```
1- Carta
2- Telegrama
3 Bulto postal\n\n>"""))

if tcorreo == 1:
    while agg == "s":
        exec("carta%d = carta[:]" % x)
        exec("print 'carta%d'" % x)
        for i in range(len(carta)):
            exec("carta%d[%d][1] = raw_input(carta[%d][0])" % (x, i, i))
        #exec("cartay = carta%d" % x)
        exec("CARTA.append(carta%d)" % x)
        x = x+1
        agg = raw_input("Desea entregar otra carta? s/n")

print CARTA
```

Comment: El código que has dejado no funciona para la acción 1. ¿Por qué usas `exec`? No entiendo muy bien su uso y su relación con lo que quieres conseguir. ¿Por qué no almacenas, por ejemplo las cartas, en una lista y puedes ir accediendo a las mismas por el índice? En lugar de tener, por ejemplo, `carta0`, `carta1`,..., tendrías `cartas[0]`, `cartas[1]`,..., pero sin necesidad de usar `exec`.

Comment: Lo utilizo para generar una variable carta1, carta2, carta3... cartan que solo me sirva para almacenar la informacion que copio de la plantilla carta que tengo. Me guarda la info y todo, pero la cosa esta cuando imprimo el contenido que tengo en CARTA, todas las que he introducido contienen la informacion de la ultima que introduje, como si se modificaran todas con la informacion de la ultima

Comment: ¿Cómo estás ejecutando el programa? Creo que todo debería estar dentro de un `while` para mantener `CARTA` actualizado pero sigo sin entender correctamente el beneficio de usar `exec` y lo que quieres conseguir con el código que pones.

Comment: Es que comence a usar exec porque necesitaba generar una variable dinamica para cada vez que deseo introducir otra carta, pero aunque las variables sean diferentes, al utilizar apprend, siempre guarda solo la ultima que introduzco modificando todas las existentes. Por ejemplo, si ya tenia 3 cartas previamente con su propia informacion, al meter la ultima, todas se modifican con la info de la ultima :/

Answer (score 2):

¡Acabo de resolverlo de la forma en que quería! se las comparto porque a alguno le puede ayudar. El problema era en la forma que copiaba la lista hacia la otra generada dinámicamente. No tengo idea por qué fallaba, pero encontré otra función `copy.deepcopy()` que hizo el trabajo adecuadamente. Acá se los comparto:

```
# coding: latin-1

import copy

CARTA = []
agg = "s"
x = 0


carta = [[None] * 2 for i in range(5)]
carta[0][0] = "Nombre del destinatario: "
carta[1][0] = "Direccion del destinatario: "
carta[2][0] = "Nombre del remitente: "
carta[3][0] = "Fecha de envio: "
carta[4][0] = "Nacionalidad: "


accion = int(raw_input ("""Buenas noches, oficina de correos. ¿Que accion desea realizar?

1- Recibir correspondencia
2- Despachar correspondencia
3- Entregar correspondencia personalmente\n\n>"""))

if accion == 1:
    tcorreo = int(raw_input("""Que tipo de correspondencia es la que trae?

    1- Carta
    2- Telegrama
    3 Bulto postal\n\n>"""))

    if tcorreo == 1:
        while agg == "s":
            exec("carta%d = copy.deepcopy(carta)" % x)
            exec("print 'carta%d'" % x)
            for i in range(len(carta)):

                exec("carta%d[%d][%d] = raw_input(carta[%d][%d])" % (x, i, 1, i,0))

            exec("CARTA.append(carta%d)" % x)
            x = x+1
            agg = raw_input("Desea entregar otra carta? s/n")

    print CARTA
```

Answer (score 1):

Moviendo el bloque:

```py
carta = [[None] * 2 for i in range(5)]
carta[0][0] = "Nombre del destinatario: "
carta[1][0] = "Direccion del destinatario: "
carta[2][0] = "Nombre del remitente: "
carta[3][0] = "Fecha de envio: "
carta[4][0] = "Nacionalidad: "
```

hacia adentro del `while`, funciona correctamente, sin necesidad de usar ningún `exec` ni la variable `x`:

```py
# coding: latin-1

CARTA = []
TELEGRAMA = []
BULTO = []
agg = "s"


accion = int(raw_input ("""Buenas noches, oficina de correos. ¿Que accion desea realizar?


1- Recibir correspondencia
2- Despachar correspondencia
3- Entregar correspondencia personalmente\n\n>"""))


if accion == 1:
    tcorreo = int(raw_input("""Que tipo de correspondencia es la que trae?


1- Carta
2- Telegrama
3 Bulto postal\n\n>"""))

if tcorreo == 1:
    while agg == "s":
        carta = [[None] * 2 for i in range(5)]
        carta[0][0] = "Nombre del destinatario: "
        carta[1][0] = "Direccion del destinatario: "
        carta[2][0] = "Nombre del remitente: "
        carta[3][0] = "Fecha de envio: "
        carta[4][0] = "Nacionalidad: "

        for i in range(len(carta)):
            carta[i][1] = raw_input(carta[i][0])

        CARTA.append(carta)

        agg = raw_input("Desea entregar otra carta? s/n ")

print CARTA
```

La línea

```py
# coding: latin-1
```

la puse porque no me aceptaba el caracter `¿`.[►](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

También me ayudó el siguiente enlace [►](https://docs.python.org/2.7/faq/programming.html?highlight=arrays#how-do-you-make-an-array-in-python), porque soy nuevo en **Python** y no entendía cómo se anexaban las listas.

Answer (score 0):

Te dejo un ejemplo de código (simplificado respecto al tuyo) que no usa `exec` y que creo que hace lo que quieres. Si no es así, por favor, modifica tu pregunta para explicar mejor qué es lo que quieres hacer. Las diferentes `cartas` se almacenan todas en `CARTA`:

```
CARTA = []
agg = "s"
x = 0

carta = [[None] * 2 for i in range(5)]
carta[0][0] = "Nombre del destinatario: "
carta[1][0] = "Direccion del destinatario: "
carta[2][0] = "Nombre del remitente: "
carta[3][0] = "Fecha de envio: "
carta[4][0] = "Nacionalidad: "

accion = int(raw_input("""Buenas noches, oficina de correos. ¿Que accion desea realizar?

1- Recibir correspondencia\n\n>"""))

if accion == 1:
    tcorreo = int(raw_input("""Que tipo de correspondencia es la que trae?

1- Carta\n\n>"""))

if tcorreo == 1:
    while agg == "s":
        for i in range(len(carta)):
            carta[i][1] = raw_input(carta[0][0])
        CARTA.append(carta)
        x = x+1
        agg = raw_input("Desea entregar otra carta? s/n")
        if agg != "s":
            break
        print CARTA
```

Comment: No funciono de esa manera que lo mandaste, tenias muchos problemas de identacion, pero lo corregi y probe, y el problema persiste. Intenta ejecutar el mio y agrega mas de una carta y despues observa que al imprimir todas las ingresadas contienen la misma info

Comment: En mi ejemplo añado cartas y al final están todas en `CARTA`. Entonces no he entendido nada de lo que quieres hacer. Modifica la pregunta y/o el código para ver si yo u otro consigue entender lo que quieres hacer....